# Geting error in Terminal after trying Rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, ubuntu, terminal, rbenv

I'm trying to run server in Ubuntu Terminal by "$rails server", and i get this error in terminal:

" /home/sergei/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in `require': cannot load such file -- rails/cli (LoadError)   from /home/sergei/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in`require'     from /usr/bin/rails:7:in `' ".

Ruby and Rails installed.
Who knows how I can resolve that?
Thanks!

Comment: Gotta start with basics like `which gem`, `which ruby`, `which rails`, `rails --version`, etc. Add the output of some of those to your question.

Comment: I know basics, thanks. But it was some project that done before. But i didn't know that i must write AGAIN "bundle install". And still doesn't know. Because that project was done and not moved to other place. All gems was installed before, and nothing was changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have two ruby versions. Please paste the output of following command:

```
$ which -a ruby
```

If you more than one than leave one and remove others.

1. Remove ruby version installed via ports (yum or whatever package manager).
2. Remove ruby version that came with OS (hardcore rm by hand).
3. Install ruby version from ports with different prefix (/usr instead of /usr/local)
4. Reinstall rubygems

Comment: We have to start with `which ruby` because you didn't. You should get an .rbenv Ruby. Then we must ask what your gems folder looks like under .rbenv, and so on...